# Is it correct to say: "you are the shape of my thoughts"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I want to tell someone that I think about him all of the time. But, in a new style. Can I say: "You are the shape of my thoughts."?

I would be thankful to have better suggestions.

Comment: "You are the shape of my thoughts" may be grammatical, but I wouldn't have a clue what you were trying to say if you said that to me.

Comment: you shape my thoughts...

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are http://english.stackexchange.com/users/186610/sryzdn and http://english.stackexchange.com/users/186611/syzd.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* say whatever you want,
but nobody is going to understand “You are the shape of my thoughts.” 
Maybe if you say it (and explain it) a few thousand times,
it’ll catch on as a new idiom.  But I wouldn’t hold my breath.

“You are much on my mind” (or “You have been much on my mind”)
are standard ways of saying that you think of a person often.